# Change last fragment to another layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I have made fragments dynamically, it depends on number of questions, for example a test have 10 questions, there will be 10 fragments, but I want to make a final fragment after the questions are done, to see the score of those questions, I want to know how to put another fragment after this questions Fragment are done

This is my getItem() method

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    List<Question> questions = currentTest.getQuestions();
    FragmentQuestion myfragment;


    currentQ = questions.get(i);
    myfragment = new FragmentQuestion();
    myfragment.setCurrentTest(currentTest);
    myfragment.setCurrentQuestion(currentQ);
    return myfragment;
    }
```

Comment: How do you attach your fragments to activity? Just use the same approach to add your last fragment, or call `replace` for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try to replace it now.